# MongoDB returns nothing when placing the model in another file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

I have a very basic server, which can be run in three ways:

1. `[BLOCK 2 ENABLED]` / `[BLOCK 1 DISABLED]`
   Defining interfaces, schema and model in the same file.
2. `[BLOCK 1 ENABLED]` / `[BLOCK 2 DISABLED]`
   Defining interfaces, schema and model in an external file: **./models/user.ts**

The content of `[BLOCK 2]` is exactly the same as the content of file: **./models/user.ts**.

> 3. In the other hand, if I move the file: **user.ts** to:
>      **./server/models/user.ts**
>      then the code works properly, but for some specific reasons I need it at:
>      **./models/user.ts**

Just in case here you have the repository:

https://github.com/napolev/mongodb-experiments

Here is the code:

**./server/server.ts** `[BLOCK 2 ENABLED]`

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as colors from 'colors';
/*/
// BLOCK 1:
import { User, IUserDocument } from '../models/user';
/*/
// BLOCK 2:
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";
export interface IUser {
    username:   string,
    password:   string,
    email:      string,
    company:    string,
}
export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {

}
export var UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    username:   String,
    password:   String,
    email:      String,
    company:    String,
});
export const User: Model<IUserDocument> = model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
//*/

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:9100/mongodb-experiments');

User.find({}, function(err, users: IUserDocument[]){
    console.log(users);
});

let message = colors.green('Hello') + ' '  + colors.red.bgYellow.underline('World') + ' ' +  colors.blue.bgRed('!!!');

console.log(message);

// To work with the Mongo Shell:
// $ cd /path/to/mongodb/bin"
// $ mongo --port 9100
// use mongodb-experiments
// db.users.insert( { username: "bill.gates", password: "windows", email: "billgates@microsoft.com", company: "Microsoft" } )
// db.users.insert( { username: "steve.jobs", password: "mac", email: "stevejobs@apple.com", company: "Apple" } );
// db.getCollection("users").find()
```

**./models/user.ts**

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

export interface IUser {
    username:   string,
    password:   string,
    email:      string,
    company:    string,
}
export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {

}
export var UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    username:   String,
    password:   String,
    email:      String,
    company:    String,
});

export const User: Model<IUserDocument> = model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
```

Suppose we have some dummy data on the database:

```
$ cd /path/to/mongodb/bin"
$ mongo --port 9100
use mongodb-experiments
db.users.insert( { username: "bill.gates", password: "windows", email: "billgates@microsoft.com", company: "Microsoft" } )
db.users.insert( { username: "steve.jobs", password: "mac", email: "stevejobs@apple.com", company: "Apple" } );
```

If I run the server with `[BLOCK 2]` enabled:

```
$ ts-node server.ts
```

I get the following output:

```
Hello World !!!
[ { _id: 5b3561bbcde3135b908cb51b,
    username: 'bill.gates',
    password: 'windows',
    email: 'billgates@microsoft.com',
    company: 'Microsoft' },
  { _id: 5b3561c1cde3135b908cb51c,
    username: 'steve.jobs',
    password: 'mac',
    email: 'stevejobs@apple.com',
    company: 'Apple' } ]
```

But If I run the server with `[BLOCK 1]` enabled:

I just get the following output:

```
Hello World !!!
```

**without** the previous entries.

The only difference I see between both ways is where are defined the interfaces, schema and model.

**EDIT 1**

I did some experiments:

With `way 1` and `way 3` mentioned above, if I do:

```
$ cd ./server/
$ tsc server.ts
$ node server.js
```

then I get the **expected output**.

But with `way 2` mentioned above, If I do:

```
$ cd ./server/
$ tsc server.ts
```

I get the following output:

```
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(61,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'NativeBuffer'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(62,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'NativeDate'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(63,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'NativeError'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(71,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Mongoose'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(72,8): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Mongoose'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(156,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CastError'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(177,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ConnectionBase'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(447,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Connection'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(463,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ValidationError'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(472,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Error'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(562,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'VirtualType'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(579,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Schema'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(888,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1018,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1072,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MongooseDocument'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1073,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MongooseDocument'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1275,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Subdocument'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1291,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Array'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1400,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentArray'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1429,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1461,10): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ObjectIdConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1469,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Decimal128'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1475,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Embedded'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1515,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Query'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1516,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentQuery'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(1948,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mquery'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(2000,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Schema'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(2248,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Aggregate'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(2411,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SchemaType'.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(2864,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts(2966,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
```

I think there are conflicts because the directory: `./models/` has its own `node_modules` directory.

Do you think is there a way to **NOT** include the dependencies:
{`mongoose`, `@types/mongoose`} on the `./server/` directory and just do it on the `./models/` directory to prevent these conflicts?

Any idea on how to make the `way 2` work?

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely you have stale `.js` file compiled from some old variant of `user.ts` somewhere. Remove all `.js` files, recompile and try again.

Comment: when running `$ ts-node server.ts` there is no `.js` file generated. Also, the `way 3` above works properly. I think the issue is because defining the interfaces, schema and model in an uncle directory (from `server.ts` point of view).

Comment: Then `ts-node` is somehow importing the wrong file. If contents of the file are the same, it should not matter where it's located.

Comment: I added: `EDIT 1` on my post above.

Comment: Oh. If `models` has its own `node_modules`, then either `node_modules` should be removed there, or `models` should be a separate package with it's own `package.json` which have it's `main` and `types` set up properly, it should be compiled separately and used as dependency in server code.

Comment: my only goal no matter what is to put the `user.ts` file on an uncle directory from `server.ts` point of view (as described on my post above: `way 2`). Is there a short way to do this?

Comment: Probably yes, but there really shouldn't be multiple `node_modules` scattered among your source code directories.

Comment: if I remove `node_modules` from `./models/`, then `tsc` compiles correctly, but when running with: `$ node server.js` I get the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'` on file: `./models/user.js`. I think we are getting close, just need the proper configuration for this.

Comment: Ah. now I see in the github repo that indeed `models` and `server` each have its own `package.json`. No you can't compile source code from more than one package in a single TypeScript compilation. You can try, but there bound to be problems.

Comment: so, what are my options, then?

Comment: combine the two into one package with single `package.json` and `node_modules`, or set up a monorepo using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) or [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), and compile separately.